# Ruby on Rails Query Result Group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, loops, activerecord

In my controller I have

```
 def services
   @services = WorkQuote.group(:work_type_id).count

  end
```

Which when ran in IRB:

```
irb(main):016:0> @services = WorkQuote.group(:work_type_id).count
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, work_type_id AS work_type_id FROM "work_quotes" GROUP BY "work_quotes"."work_type_id"
=> {1=>2, 3=>1}
```

Notice that the result is {1=>2, 3=>1}. In my controller I want to make a loop that builds a new array where the number to the left of the `=>` is resolved by being inserted into this `WorkType.find(number to the left of =>).worktype`

So the new array would look like [Install=>2, Repair=>1} assuming that `WorkType.find(1).worktype = Install` and `WorkType.find(3).worktype = Repair`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me although I am sure there is a cleaner way of doing this.

Basically grabbed each value with .each_key and pushed it into an array. Next I made a loop to grab the "count" which is the right side of each hash. Also in the loop I made an array that combined the resolved name of the WorkType id and the "count".

I realize that @printcount isn't needed in this situation.

```
 @services = WorkQuote.group(:work_type_id).count
   @printservices = []
   @services.each_key {|key| @printservices.push(WorkType.find(key).worktype) }

   @services = @services.to_a

   @printcount = []
   @printdisplay = []
   iz = 0

    while iz < @services.size
      @printcount[iz] = @services[iz][1]
      @printdisplay[iz] = [@printservices[iz], @services[iz][1]]
      iz = iz + 1
    end
```